# ROR maintain history of object updates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I have a model which I want to store a history of changes to, my plan is to rather than update an object create a new one and on a show only fetch the latest version.

This plan presents a number of difficulties firstly the id will be different after a update I indend to get around this by keeping a second ID column which will be the same for all updates of that instance.

to that end I have created a SQLite sequence for this second coloumn.

my question is how can I get values from this sequence in the model/controller as I will only want to get from it on first time the object is created, secondly how can I use this second ID column as the URL for the object so it is fixed throughout updates.

Many Thanks,

Comment: `acts_as_versioned` gem might be what you're looking for https://github.com/technoweenie/acts_as_versioned.

Comment: I think your design is little complicated. From your requirements, you can go for two tables. One will be for live_data and one will be for storing histories ( lets call it data_histories). Create associations between them . live_data has_many data_histories. Here data_histories will have a column called live_data_id which remains constant for all histories . Each time a change is made to live_data table, push a copy to histories and make the change. Much cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the PaperTrail gem. It might do what you want and sidestep those issues completely.

https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail